# Wedge product linearly independent question

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ be $n$ linearly independent one-form in $\Omega(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and suppose that $\omega$ is a $k$- form such that $1 \leq k \leq n-1$.

Show that if $\omega \wedge  a_i = 0$ for all $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ then $\omega$ is the null $k$-form.

---

I know that $a_1 \wedge a_2 \wedge  \cdots \wedge  a_n \neq 0$ since they are linearly independent, and I also know that $a_i \wedge  a_i = 0$. One other ideia is to decompose $\omega$ as a combination of wedge products of one-form factors and see if that, toghether with the fact that the exterior product of $\omega$ with each $a_i$ vanishes, give me that $\omega = 0$. Tried all that and couldn't get anywhere.

Can someone please help me here? Thanks!

Comment: Are you in an $n$-dimensional vector space (or manifold)? I assume so.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh sorry. Yeah, n-dimensional vector space :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $I$ varies over increasing $k$-tuples, $a_I = a_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge a_{i_k}$ gives a basis for $\Lambda^k(V)$. Write
$$\omega = \sum_I c_I a_I.$$
Consider $I^o$ fixed and choose any $i\notin I^o$. Wedge this expression with $a_i$.
$$0=\omega\wedge a_i = \sum_I c_I a_{I}\wedge a_i = c_{I^o}a_{I^o}\wedge a_i + \dots.$$
These forms are linearly independent when $i\notin I$ (and the other terms are $0$). Thus, we get $c_{I^o}=0$.

Comment: Why all the other terms are 0? Isn't possible that after fixed $I^0$ we have for example $I^j$ such that $i \notin I^j$?

Comment: The argument applies to any $I^o$.

Comment: But I can't see (yet) why "(and the other terms are 0)".

Comment: Basic property of wedge product? $a_i\wedge a_i=0$.

Comment: Yes, but why necessarily $i$ will be in all other $I^j$ where $j \neq I_0$ as the fixed one for example?

Comment: I never said that. Read carefully.

Comment: $c_{I^0}a_{I^0} \wedge a_i + c_{I^1}a_{I^1} \wedge a_i + \cdots$... I can't see why $ c_{I^1}a_{I^1} \wedge a_i $ will vanish by the property $a_i \wedge a_i = 0$ since $i$ might not be in $I^1$ :/

Comment: I never said that. I said all the nonzero terms will be linearly independent.